# Error for json Service String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I have tried every thing but it is giving me still the same error.Everything was working fine before SSL implementation on the website. Here is the URL for my service [MY LIST](https://www.fitindia.in/index.jsp?it=cat_post&id=5). the error is The Value 
times but cant find anything

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject this is the error it is showing in logs

Comment: can you write your code?

Comment: u should provide the `code` u have tried and `logcat` error

Comment: Please show the code where you are trying to parse the result. You are trying to read a JSONObject where there is a String.

Comment: http://codepad.org/E4q1QH3c  here is the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your address contains `https` otherwise you will get a `302 Found` which is telling you to redirect to the https endpoing.

Your url should be:

`https://www.fitindya.in/windex.php?itfpage=cat_post&id=5`

and not

```
http://www.fitindya.in/windex.php?itfpage=cat_post&id=5
```

What you can do for example is

```
String strUrl = getUrlData.replace("http://","https://")+"windex.php?itfpage=cat_post&id="+id;
```

You also need to have "www" on the link.

```
if(!strUrl.contains("https://www."))
    strUrl.replace("https://","https://www.");
```

Comment: Are you really sure you changed it to https? Because I just tested your code and I got no problems whatsoever. What is your log on `strUrl`?

Comment: You're still missing the `www.`

Comment: oh thanx dude. how could i be such a pathetic looser.

Comment: don't worry friend. We've all been there :) Have a nice day.

Comment: thanx dude . u real mvp. thanx for saving my ass

Answer (score 0):

### You can try in this way

```
if (json.getString(itfdata) != null ) {


                    String itfdata = json.getString("itfdata");
                    Log.d("Json Response itfdata is--->","" + itfdata.toString());

            }


    try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(itfdata.toString());
                //JSONArray array = new JSONArray(itfdata.toString());

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    list.add(array.getString(i));
                    System.out.println("I Position : " + array.getString(i));

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```